# Output XMLHttpRequest to DIV via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

I am trying to list out the station names of the local transit system via an API call in pure JS. I want to loop through the station names(45 of them) and output them into a list inside of  **div id="stationDiv"**

All I am getting is a list of 45 empty object Elements listed inside the div. I can't seem to get the loop to output correctly.

#### Sample of XML file

```
<root>
<uri>
<![CDATA[ http://api.bart.gov/api/stn.aspx?cmd=stns ]]>
</uri>
<stations>
<station>
<name>12th St. Oakland City Center</name>
<abbr>12TH</abbr>
<gtfs_latitude>37.803664</gtfs_latitude>
<gtfs_longitude>-122.271604</gtfs_longitude>
<address>1245 Broadway</address>
<city>Oakland</city>
<county>alameda</county>
<state>CA</state>
<zipcode>94612</zipcode>
</station>
//44 more station's below this
```

#### Set up calling the API:

```
var URL ="http://api.bart.gov/api/stn.aspx?cmd=stns&key=MW9S-E7SL-26DU-VV8V"; //public key used
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET",URL,false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    console.log("connection successful");
} else {
    console.log("server returned a status code of " + oHttp.status);
}
```

#### loop that is not working:

```
var x1=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("station");

function postNames(station) {
    var x = station.length;
    var n = 0;
    var element = document.getElementById('stationDiv');
    var html = '<ul>';
    while(n < x) {
      html += '<li>' + station[n] + '</li>';
      n++;
    }
    html += '</ul>';
    element.innerHTML = html;
}

postNames(x1);
```

Thank you in advance, I have multiple books and 20 tabs open in front of me but just can't seem to get it to output correctly.

PURE JS only please.

Comment: Making a synchronous Ajax call is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
var x1=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("station");

var postNames = function(station) {
    var x = station.length;
    var n = 0;
    var element = document.getElementById('stationDiv');
    var html = '<ul>';
    while(n < x) {
      html += '<li>' + station[n].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue + '</li>';
      n++;
    }
    html += '</ul>';
    element.innerHTML = html;
}

postNames(x1);
```

Comment: This works! It seems all it needed was the .getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue portion, would you mind explaining how this works or linking to relevant documentation?